# Extended desktop 'washes out' image on primary Monitor

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card

BLUF:  Primary monitor looks fine in cloned desktop mode with secondary monitor, washes out in extended desktop mode.  Can washout be prevented?

I have two monitors hooked up to my computer, a 'primary' monitor connected by HDMI to an Nvidia GTX 970 and my secondary monitor connected by DVI cable.  The Primary monitor is an AOC e2752She 27" and the secondary is a 24" ASUS VW246H.

I had them in extended desktop mode and between the two noticed the ASUS had much brighter whites and much darker darks compared to the AOC.  I adjusted the monitors' brightness and contrast until I was okay with the two sitting next to each other but it was still very noticeable.  Today I changed the setting from extended desktop to cloned desktop, and the AOC monitor's darks became much darker.  Believing it to be a trick of my eyes I played with turning it back and forth between extended and cloned and actually watched the primary AOC monitor 'flick' to a darker richer picture shortly after swapping to cloned mode.

Any idea what might be causing this, and if I can force it to occur while extending my display?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer and wanted to share.  Source for my solution is this link, which may give more detailed reading:  https://pcmonitors.info/articles/correcting-hdmi-colour-on-nvidia-and-amd-gpus/

Issue: My monitor connected by HDMI is being detected as having a lower range of color by my graphics card

Solution:  If you open the Nvidia control panel (The link has separate steps for AMD users) under display there is an option to adjust desktop color settings.  Select the monitor connected by HDMI, choose the bubble for 'Use Nvidia Settings' and adjust the dynamic range from limited (16-235) to Full (0-255)  Richer colors using the full dynamic range of color.

Alternatively, alter the digital color format from RGB to YCbCr444 for very similar results.  I hope this helps someone else with similar issues.